# How Databricks processes the incoming messages from EventHub?

Tags: azure-eventhub, azure-databricks

Being novice to real time continuous data processing scenarios, would like to know how the incoming continuous series of messages get processed via databricks, whether those are processed Sequential one by one or in Parallel way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is to use Spark on Databricks to ingest data from EventHub. This is done by consuming a message queue. If only one consumer is used to read from the queue, the messages will be processed sequentially. However, if multiple consumers are used it is possible to process multiple messages in parallel.

Check out these examples for more info as well:

- https://lenadroid.github.io/posts/connecting-spark-and-eventhubs.html
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-databricks/databricks-stream-from-eventhubs